# Unix check how many days ago a date was from today

Tags: bash, unix

I have a date in this format:

`2020-02-21T13:47:18.488+11:00`

How can I check how many days ago this was compared to today's date? I know there's plenty of things I can do with `date -d` but unsure how to do it with that specific format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this using [Epoch time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch):

```
#!/bin/bash

now=$(date +%s)
old=$(date -d '2020-02-21T13:47:18.488+11:00' '+%s')
echo "$(( (now-old)/(3600*24) )) days"
```

```
135 days
```

Comment: +1 This is a straightforward way to do it.  One caveat to bear in mind is that we don't always mean "86400 seconds" when we talk about days.  If it is 6am for me, I might say something that happened at 8am the day before happened "yesterday" or "one day ago," but this will compute zero days elapsed.  Additionally, this approach will say that 00:01 and 23:01 on November 1st, 2020 are one day apart, despite being on the same day, because in my time zone that day is _25_ hours long.  And then there are leap seconds.

Comment: OP should feel free to adapt to his needs ;)